# Image upload web service with view only mode

Tags: images, picasa, flickr

Is there a web service/site like flickr etc which enables me to upload photos to server and then provides a URL which i can share with viewers but they can only view the photos and not download it with a right click from the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to provide the ability as per u. Because there are variuos screen capturing methods and tools too.

You can share the image in view only mode with the help of flash  but i dont know the particular site .

Comment: Like was said before, it's nigh on impossible to stop completely, but using Flash protection of some sort would stop plenty if people, methinks.

Comment: so i've to upload a flash file ? which web service?

Answer (score 0):

Many people would love this ability, but it is ... dare I say, impossible? to prevent people from getting a copy of your images out of their browser, one way or another.  I can only imagine that porn site operators have been struggling with this since the boom of their business several years ago.

If your viewers can't directly Right-click|Save As, then they can check their browser cache.  If the images are somehow not cached, then there's always Alt+PrtScrn (or just a whole-screen PrtScrn) and paste into image-editor-of-choice.

I hope that someone has an answer for you that addresses all the various ways that are available to get at images in a browser.  I'm interested to see the other potential answers.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with  the other posters, so the approach might be to make it less convenient for a visitor to obtain the images. Things I can think of are:

- Use of Javascript to intercept the right-click. This can be done, one site that used to do it was [seeda.co.uk](http://www.seeda.co.uk) - The South East England Development Agency: they wanted to discourage people from using the low-res web friendly logo in printed material or large artworks and soright-clicking directed the visitor to the official logo press pack with higher resolution images
- A directive on your Apache server to stop someone linking to your image from another site. Check out Apache Cookbook by O'Reilly
- Visibly (or invisibly) watermarking your images to discourage unauthorised use
- You could make your images available as a downloaded application which intercepts screenshots
- Also, you'll notice this with flickr, it has the CSS trick of making a preview image a background attribute so right clicking saves a "spaceball.gif", you have to click through to the full size image - which you are allowed to save
- Use of Creative Commons licensing to advise visitors